# Magento 2 Difference between default.xml and default_head_blocks.xml

Tags: magento2, default.xml

In Magento 2 Theme , `default.xml` and `default_head_blocks.xml` files are located in `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\Magento_Theme\layout`

can anyone tell me what is the difference between these two files ?

Answer (score 4):

> default.xml: defines the page layout.
>
> default_head_blocks.xml: defines the scripts, images, and meta data
> included in pages’  section.

You can read more about this here: [from magento doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html)

Example of **default_head_blocks.xml**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>
    
        <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>
        
        <!-- Add external resources -->
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

Example of **default.xml**

> app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
...
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\Sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
...
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but we can also use head section in default.xml also so why default_head_blocks.xml concept has come.

Comment: When you will add js and css using default_head_blocks.xm it will be add for all pages and in default.xml with in every module head will be for that module specific

Comment: like as some thing you want to add in head for catalog section only then you will use default.xml inside Magento_Catalog.

Answer (score 1):

The basic view of all Magento storefront pages in defined in two page configuration layout files located in the Magento_Theme module:

1) `<Magento_Theme_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`: defines the page layout.

2) `<Magento_Theme_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`: defines the scripts, images, and meta data included in pages’ `<head>` section.

These basic page configuration layouts are extended in other Magento modules and in Magento themes.

You can also extend or override these files in your custom theme.

**REF** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer,but we can also define head section in default.xml so why concept of default_head_blocks.xml has come

Comment: @SanjayShiyal It's basic separation of responsibility. One adds the markup and the other adds the look and feel. It's like breaking the code in two functions or separating the logic in two classes.

Answer (score 1):

`default_head_blocks.xml` is a specific layout of head section, and this file is called in `default.xml` : `<update handle="default_head_blocks"/>` so if you want to add in head section `css`, `javascript`, `static assets`, The recommended way is to add them in `default_head_blocks.xml`.

You can very well add them in `default.xml` one and it works, but your code you will not be pretty as Magento do, Since we use Magento, we should apply the recommended way.

> JavaScript, CSS and other static assets are added in the 
>   section of a page configuration file. The default look of a Magento
>   store page  is defined by
>   app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml.
>   The recommended way to add CSS and JavaScript is to extend this file
>   in your custom theme, and add the assets there.